# Apple SVG Badge Not Showing Right Border

Tags: html, css, svg

OK... i've spent probably the last 2 days fixing the whole website because of Apple's money greedy guidelines. Its so funny. But that on side, im stuck with the https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjhnc.jpg

I have |

```

```
.apple-btn {
        background:url('img/stores/btn-app-store.svg');
        background-size: cover;
        width:200px;
        height:60px;
    }
```

```

svg loads, but the border on the right side is missing as you see in the picture.

Comment: This might be because of 2 reasons. 

 1. Your SVG does not have the right side
 2. What happens if you increase the width lets say 210px? It might be that your svg is 200px but because the paths in svg hits the border of the image it get's a little bit cropped.

Comment: I have tried increasing the width. Either bottom border will disappear then, and right will appear. Either way, one border will be missing.

Svg is fine when i open it in google-chrome and its working fine in different place in my website.

Comment: Can you please recreate the problem in jsfiddle, so that it will be easier to check the problem?

Comment: I have the svg on my PC, im not using any links and also i have bootstrap calls of img-responsive. Thats all.

Comment: what happens when you add this line of style to .apple-btn 

`transform: scale(0.9)`?
also try to set `background-size to contain`. cover might be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use contain instead of cover

```
background-size: contain;
```